# Working example to group layers in LayerSwitcher of OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am looking for a nice plugin with working examples to group layers in OL 2.11/2.13.1 LayerSwitcher. I found several emails and posts explainig that GeoExt is the best way to do this, but have only access to OL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "unofficial" Control called OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcherGroups which you can find here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rkj/openlayers/master/lib/OpenLayers/Control/LayerSwitcherGroups.js

Just include the Script after your OpenLayers.js and use it like this:

```
    var group = [hospitals, schools];
                for (var i=0; i < group.length; i++) { group[i].group = 'Hospitals + Schools'; }

    var group = [streets, police];
                for (var i=0; i < group.length; i++) { group[i].group = 'Streets + Police'; }


 map.addLayers([osm, streets, hospitals, schools, police]);
```

[image: Layerswitcher with groups]
[image: Layerswitcher with groups folded / unfolded group]

Apart from that there is a pretty old layerswitcher.js patch 
https://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/1086
https://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/attachment/ticket/1086/LayerSwitcher.js.patch
 Perhaps you could also use this and adapt it to the newer Layerswitcher.js version. The logic of this patch has been used for the Layer-Switcher-Control of HS-Layers where you can also find some more 'inspiration':

http://redmine.ccss.cz/projects/hslayers/repository/changes/trunk/source/HSLayers/Control/LayerSwitcher.js

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, I tried it with OL2.11 and 2.13.1 but it doesn't work, what version have you tried? when you said `Just include the Script after your OpenLayers.js` you meant in the script tag or in the OL Control lib root?

Comment: sorry for the noise, I just needed to add `map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcherGroups());`, so it works great, thanks!!

Comment: how to use  open layer 2 layer switcher  in Open Layers 3.