# One layerswitcher option to open two wms layers

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, layer-switcher

I have two WMS layers Martello_Towers and Martello_Towers_Range. Rather than have two options in Layerswitcher I would like one option to control both layers. They are both in the same projection. I've tried obvious things like `layers: "egm715:DLR_Martello_Towers" + "egm715:DLR_Martello_Towers_Range",` or trying to combine them in a variable.

I've seen the solution at [Working example to group layers in LayerSwitcher of OpenLayers 2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154915/working-example-to-group-layers-in-layerswitcher-of-openlayers-2) But grouping them isn't what I'm after.

```
// Martello Towers
    dlr_martello_towers_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("DLR Martello Towers", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/egm715/wms",
        {
        layers: "egm715:DLR_Martello_Towers",
        transparent: true
        }, {
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        opacity: 0.7,
        visibility: false
        }
    );
    dlr_mtowers_range_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("DLR Martello Towers Firing Range (WMS)", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/egm715/wms",
        {
        layers: "egm715:DLR_Martello_Towers_Range",
        transparent: true
        }, {
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        opacity: 0.4,
        visibility: false
        }
    );
```

Comment: Put it to send a comma separated list as "layers".

Comment: Hi user30184, can you let me know what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show those two layers always together then just ask the WMS server to send them together. Order of layers in the list matters. The first layer is rendered first the following one on top of that. About like this

```
   // Martello Range and Towers
        dlr_martello_range_and_towers_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("DLR Martello Towers", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/egm715/wms",
            {
            layers: "egm715:DLR_Martello_Towers_Range,egm715:DLR_Martello_Towers",
        transparent: true
        }, {
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        opacity: 0.7,
        visibility: false
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks user30184. that worked great. I forgot to add the 'egm715' bit. Thanks.